# Issue with Merging Sheets from Different Workbooks Resulting in Blank Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to merge several sheets from different workbooks with identical columns. Despite having the same structure, some of the sheets may only contain a header row or lack information altogether.

To streamline my workflow, I've been using VBA along with a command button to merge these sheets into a single worksheet within another workbook. While the process generally works as intended, I've noticed a significant number of empty rows in the final merged worksheet. Additionally, there have been instances where the header row is duplicated multiple times.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why these blank rows are appearing and how to prevent the duplication of header rows. Your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

```
Private Sub cmdCombine_Click()
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim DestinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceFile As String
    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim HeaderRow As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Set the source folder path
    SourceFolder = "C:\Users\v1kvazir\OneDrive - University of Edinburgh\Data\Raw\"
    
    ' Set the current workbook
    Set CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a new worksheet named "Data" or use it if it already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set DestinationWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If DestinationWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Set DestinationWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        DestinationWorksheet.Name = "Data"
    End If
    
    ' Loop through all files in the folder
    SourceFile = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.xlsx")
    Do While SourceFile <> ""
        ' Disable screen updating to prevent flickering
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' Open each source workbook
        Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & SourceFile)
        
        ' Assuming the data is in the first sheet, change "Sheet1" if needed
        Set SourceWorksheet = SourceWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        
        ' Copy the header row
        Set HeaderRow = SourceWorksheet.Rows(1)
        HeaderRow.Copy
        
        ' Find the last row and last column with data in the source worksheet
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastRow = 1
    End If
End With
        
        ' Copy data from the source worksheet to the destination worksheet
        SourceWorksheet.Rows("2:" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=DestinationWorksheet.Cells(DestinationWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
        SourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file
        SourceFile = Dir
    Loop
    ' Enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Do some formating and make the data sheet better
    ' Clear all formats before applying any new format
    Worksheets("Data").Cells.ClearFormats
    'Autofit all the columns that have data
   Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   ' Check if the first row is empty and delete it
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Rows(1)) = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Data").Rows(1).Delete
    End If
 ' Find the header and change the font and backcolor
    Dim lcolumn As Long
    lcolumn = Worksheets("data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(1, lcolumn).Address()).Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(1, lcolumn).Address()).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(1, lcolumn).Address()).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    
' find the first row and make it bold
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Worksheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(lrow, 1).Address()).Font.Bold = True
    
    
    MsgBox "Data copied successfully to the 'Data' sheet in the current workbook!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Operation Complete"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Some test data would be useful so we can try it. Use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from Excel or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Just as an fyi, you don't need to use `Range(Cells(1,1).Address(), Cells(lRow,1).Address())`, you can use `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lRow,1)` instead. You're also using `HeaderRow.Copy` but don't do anything with it which makes it even more interesting you have multiple headers going on unless some start at row 2. One last thing I'm seeing rn is that it might be due to using `With Sheets("Sheet1")` when going for your `lastRow` instead of `With SourceWorksheet`.

Comment: Problem aside - if the workbook is always going to be `ThisWorkbook` it's three less characters to type if you just use `ThisWorkbook` each time rather `CurrentWorkbook`